# Operation over grouped column Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

In a Hive table I have actual sales and prediction for them. so the data looks like:

```
item   date  salesDol   salesUnit   predictionU
1    1/1/2016  5.99      1            0.9
1    1/1/2016  5.49      1            0.9
1    2/1/2016  5.99      1            0.84
1    3/1/2016  6.04      1            0.92
```

For calculating the avg price I do:

```
create table data1 as 
select item, date, predictionU from data
JOIN
(select sum(salesDol) as totDol, sum(salesUnit) as totUnit from data);
```

So in each row I have `totDol` and `totUnit`. Now in order to get final extrapolated sales units I try:

```
create table data2 as 
    select item, date, sum(predictionU)*totDol/totUnit from data1 group by item, date;
```

then I get error saying:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Expression not in
>   GROUP BY key 'totDol'

I am not able to understand why Hive is asking me to include `totDol` also in the group by clause. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
select item, date, predictionU,
       sum(salesDol) over () as totDol,
       sum(salesUnit) over () as totUnit
from data;
```

You can then include this in your final query:

```
select item, date, predictionU,
       sum(salesDol) over () as totDol,
       sum(salesUnit) over () as totUnit,
       (preditionU * sum(salesDol) over () / sum(salesUnit) over ())
from data;
```

Comment: I asked simplified version of the my query. If I have `sum(case when sls_type_c='regular' then tot_sales else 0 end) as regular_sls` then I just need to do `sum(tot_sales) over (partition by sls_type_c='regular') as regular_sls`. correct? @abhiieor

Comment: No, you would do `sum(case when sls_type_c = 'regular' then tot_sales else 0 end) over ()` for the sum of all "regular" sales.